Why use universal property to show $(S^{-1}A)\otimes_A M\cong S^{-1}M$ (and other similar problems)
I'm currently going through Vakil, and I'm having some trouble understanding why the universal property is used in many cases to show that a morphism is well-defined. For example, Vakil provides the following exercise:
"If $S$ is a multiplicative subset of $A$ and $M$ is an $A$-module, describe a natural isomorphism $(S^{-1}A)\otimes_A M\cong S^{-1}M$ (both as $S^{-1}A$-modules and $A$-modules)."
I simply constructed an explicit morphism by $a/s \otimes m \mapsto am / s$, which I believe to clearly be well-defined, and both a morphism of $S^{-1}A$-modules as well as $A$-modules, and then checking that this is surjective and injective. However, when validating my proof by checking online, other sources seem to define the equivalent map $(S^{-1}A)\times M\to S^{-1}M$ by $(a/s, m) \mapsto am / s$ and then using the universal propererty to show that this induces the map I defined.
My question is then: why is this required? I've seen this in other examples as well.
Thanks in advance!

I'm impressed that you see well-definedness so clearly :) For me, personally, it's not even clear (without using the uniprop) that $a / s \otimes m$ should be non-zero if $am / s$ is. In any case, by the uniprop showing that your map is well-defined is the same as showing that the map on the product is bilinear, which is generally speaking easier because the product you understand completely, so why not use it?

To put it differently, I think you have it backwards: The tensor product is fully characterized by its universal property, and this is the primary thing about it. Why, then, would I choose to work on the level of tensors when (a) even showing that an elementary tensor is non-zero can require a non-trivial amount of divination and (b) I have the uniprop and manipulating bilinear maps is generally pretty easy?

@BenSteffan Hmm I guess the confusion might be why the map would't be well defined by the same argument that the map on the (non-tensor) product is? How do you know that the map from the (non-tensor) product doesn't come with the same potential problems? Thanks again!

The ordinary product is not plagued by the same issues: An element of $V \times W$ is just a pair $(v, w)$. In particular, this pair is non-zero if both $v$ and $w$ are. This is not necessarily true for elementary tensors (a common pitfall). In this sense bilinear maps have steadier footing than maps from the tensor product, and checking that something is bilinear is usually not too hard: In your case it's basically completely free since the map is just a scalar multiplication map.

To put a slightly different spin on it, the question of whether $v \otimes w = 0$ in $V \otimes W$ is the same as asking whether for all bilinear maps $f\colon V \times W \to Z$ we have $f(v, w) = 0$, and if you want to define a map on $V \otimes W$ directly you'll usually have to answer this question plus more (relations between non-elementary tensors, say). In that sense you cannot escape the universal property at all (as one would expect since it characterizes the tensor product fully), you can only make things harder for yourself :)

@BenSteffan Hmm okay I see. Seems I was assuming that the tensor product is "nicer" than it really is; also guess that I might've justified this by using the universal property unconsciously. Thanks for the help!
